Is a godlike being inevitable?
Over time, many complex things arise given simpler beginnings. After all, we are arguably much more complex than the initial state of the universe. Does this imply that an even more complex being like god will eventually be “created” naturally?

A god is not just a powerful natural being. In Western philosophy, a god is someone who transcends nature.

Yes. A pantheistic theology + a dynamic ontology makes an evolving deity natural

Consider the dinosaurs. They populated earth much longer than homo sapiens but none of them got human like intelligence. In the other hand computers have increased power every year, and companies like Google know more about more people than any government.

As a practical problem, this universe may not provide a life-sustaining environment anywhere to reach sufficient power (in any sense) to be godlike.
And, more urgently, various cosmic calamities like death meteorites can eliminate all life on earth any given time.
In a theoretical stable universe supporting life forever, we can imagine any thing continuously increasing in power. This might be a technical device rather than a biological being due to all the friction that comes with the circle of life. Not every power can increase infinitely, but there are certainly powers that can grow beyond certain thresholds.
One could reasonably claim that homo sapiens is already "godlike" for some definition (though not for other definitions). Certainly we have some exceptional traits among the lifeforms of this planet.
However given how long dinosaurs existed without achieving human like intelligence, even our intelligence does not seem like it happened inevitably, but it seems mostly circumstantial as a result of favorable unique conditions.

Setting aside the ambiguity that comes with "complex" and ignoring aspects of god like "super natural", creator of the universe and so on and just going for the very powerful, very knowledgeable and fast travel or just very intricate and complex.
Well you could take a look at atoms. More precisely their cores or nucleus. There are several forces at play, some make it more stable others make it less stable, so while heavier nuclei can form and did form, beyond some point it's almost impossible to find anything stable.
Now for nuclei it's a bit cheating because they didn't become bigger over time (at least not in the sense that one might picture), but they were fused under high temperatures and pressure.
Either way you could conceptually picture forces that attract and repel, which allow for an initial growth, but also lead to a static or dynamic equilibrium point upon which complexity doesn't grow. Or which go through waves of growing and dying like most living things if you look at them from an outside perspective.
So it's not inevitable that complexity will always increase.


“Is a godlike being inevitable?” is an old question in a new outfit:
One of the classical attempts to prove the existenc of God is the
cosmological argument, as developed by Thomas Aquinas. See
Cosmological argument.
Your cosmological argumentation goes the other way round: God is not
the creator of the universe, but the universe is the creator of God.
Indeed, structure formation on different scales by self-organisation
is a leading principle in current cosmology. It was also the subject of
the theological and cosmological ideas of Teilhard de Chardin.
Nevertheless scientific cosmology and theology are two separate
domains with different methods. The history of the cosmological
argument and of similar general principles from the philosophy of
nature did not succeed to explain and to support the content of
religious beliefs.

IMO we should accept the limit of our present cognitive capabilities and the bounded validity of our philosophical and scientific principles. We should not rely on thoughts which - at present - are pure speculation.
